# call a javascript function within a while loop

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a php while loop that iterates through a series of records for printing.  This works fine.  Now I need to add in an isbn barcode.  I have a similar program that does this through javascript, and I used it in a function here, the function is:

```
<script>
function get_bar() {
    var isbn = $('#isbn').val();
$("#barcode").barcode(isbn, "ean13",{barWidth:3.00, barHeight:35, fontSize:20, output:"bmp"});
}
```

I am calling this within the while loop just at the end of it.  it works for the first record I need it in (the input), but not any of the subsequent records.  This file could have up to 100 pages that will need to be printed out.  here is a sample of the php code:

```
$result = $conn->query("select * from ship_assign where po = '$po' limit 0,10");
$pages = $result->num_rows;

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$isbn10 = $row['isbn10'];
$isbn = $row['isbn13'];
$qty = $row['qty'];
$paid = $row['paid'];
...
?>
<script>
function get_bar() {
    var isbn = $('#isbn').val();
 $("#barcode").barcode(isbn, "ean13",{barWidth:3.00, barHeight:35, fontSize:20, output:"bmp"});
 }
</script> 
<div id="page">
<div id="topper">
 <input id="isbn" value="<?php echo $isbn;?>" style="width: 200px;" placeholder="ISBN13" />
<script>
get_bar();
</script>

</body>
</html>
<?php
$x++;
} //END OF WHILE STATEMENT

$conn->close();
?>
```

I have eliminated a section of the html and php for brevity since that all works.
How do I get this function to work on all iterations for the loop??

Comment: by the time javascript runs, php is completely done. php happens on the server and generates output (html and javascript) that is sent to the client. The client gets that and parses the html and runs the javascript completely independent of php on their computer, not the server. The code you are writing will just call the same function over and over on their machine, not inside of a loop or anything. PHP doesn't run javascript, it outputs javascript code for the client to run.

Comment: Any reason why people are downvoting this?  At lease be adult enough to explain to me why.  I, like others posting on here are trying to learn.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP is a server side language. Once the PHP code is finished running it returns all the markup that it made to the browser.

In other words you cannot run a javascript function inside php code.

What you will need to do is spit everything out using php THEN run all of your javascript functions once the page has loaded.

Comment: Makes Sense.  Thank you for clearing that up for me.